# speech recognition service is not available on system on Android 11 Beta

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, speech-recognition

I am getting "**speech recognition service is not available on system on Android 11 Beta**" error on android 11 beta in my ionic 4 App.

I am using [Cordova-plugin-speechrecognition](https://github.com/pbakondy/cordova-plugin-speechrecognition) plugin in my ionic app.
Below are the configuration in my package.json:

cordova-android: 9.0.0

ionic-webview: 4.2.0

cordova-plugin-speechrecognition: 1.2.0

In older versions of android feature is working as expected

Comment: did you make sure that at least one recognition service is installed? on most devices, the recognition-service of the Google app (package ID com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox) is used a recognition service; if that app is missing, try installing it and testing again

Answer (score 1):

In Android 11 the connection to the voice recognition service must be done manually (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/package-visibility-use-cases). Adding next code in AndroidManifest.xml worked for me:

```xml
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action 
         android:name="android.speech.RecognitionService"/>
    </intent>
</queries>
```